# DialogFlow iframe missing microphone Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, dialogflow-es

i was building a phonegap application and I was using the embedded webview of Dialogflow cause I wanted to add my agent to my application

in my browser in looked like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1GMa.jpg

however in my android phone when I previewed it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1GMa.jpg

I only added this portion of my code

```
<iframe
    width="350"
    height="430"
    src="<!-- dialogflow agent link -->">
</iframe>
```

how can I bring the microphone icon back?

*edit

i think it has something to do with https. I tried uploading my files using firebase and launch the website on my phone's browser and the microphone icon was already back. I think the icon is not found since I'm only running on localhost.

Comment: Please answer your own question if you've found a adequate answer!

Comment: i havent found a solution to my problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe
    allow="microphone;"
    width="350"
    height="430"
    src="<!-- dialogflow agent link -->">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Please post an answer , and make a comment if you guess how something should be goes